# Regex logic for a 3 digits code with specific 1 digit Alphabetic and Numbers

Tags: regex

I need help on this to write logic for regex expression for the following conditions. The user keyed code should have

3 Bytes max 
1st byte can have alpha (specifically A, B, P) or all 3 numbers 
2nd & 3rd bytes must be numeric
No special characters allowed.

```
Examples, 
A23      - match
B45      - match
P71      - match
A3       - match
418      - match
91       - match            

C23      - not match
AC2      - not match
D3       - not match
```

I tried the expression, but no luck. The logic is

```
alphaNumericRegExp =/[A,B,P][0-9]{3}/

Matcher matcher = mask.matcher(service.getRacprCd1());
Matcher matcher1=digitPattern.matcher(service.getRacprCd1());

if (!matcher.matches()) {
    vectErrMsgs.add("Pr code  is not valid. " );          
}
```

Comment: `if (your_string.matches("[ABP0-9]?[0-9]{2}")) { /* valid */ }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: And? Does it work?

Comment: Yes it worked with minor change for my requirement. [ABP0-9]?[0-9]{1,2}. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor. This is my first posting and I am not sure how to accept the answer. Is there any accept answer button? I tried to search but could not find.

Comment: got it. thanks. I accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
alphaNumericRegExp =/[ABP0-9]?[0-9]{1,2}/
```

With `matcher.matches()`, it requires a full string match, no need adding `^` and `$` anchors. It matches:

- `[ABP0-9]?` - an optional `A`, `B`, `P`, or digit
- `[0-9]{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits

Note that a `|` inside a character class makes it match the *literal* pipe symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into logical pieces. The first char can be A, B, P, a number, or (if I understand correctly) nothing. Therefore:

```
[ABP\d]?
```

Then there needs to be 1 or 2 digits.

```
\d{1,2}
```

So all together,

```
^[ABP\d]?\d{1,2}$
```

One gotcha, this allows a single digit. I can't tell from your question if that is allowed. If the code has to be at least 2 chars long, remove the `?`